# VBA Delete Sheets Based on Name Found in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, for-loop

Hi every month I get a report with historical worksheets in my workbook and I have to delete these worksheets before I do my analysis. My current macro deletes the sheets but I have to type out each name one by one. Is there an easier way to do this? Like have my FOR loop, loop through an array of names?

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
  If ws.Name = "Summary" Then
    ws.Visible = True
  ElseIf ws.Name = "Novemberdata" Then
    ws.Delete
  ElseIf ws.Name = "Novembersales" Then
    ws.Delete
  ElseIf ws.Name = "Decemberdata" Then
    ws.Delete
  ElseIf ws.Name = "DecemberSales" Then
    ws.Delete
  ElseIf ws.Name = "Januarydata" Then
    ws.Delete
  ElseIf ws.Name = "January Sales" Then
    ws.Delete
  Else: ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
  End If
 Next
```

Comment: Is there some pattern to the sheets that should be deleted or those that should be hidden? For example, do all sheets whose name begins with a month need to be deleted? Or are some kept? This will help make the code simpler if there's some pattern.

Comment: Hi @FlexYourData I figured it out! It really went over my head haha. There was no pattern. I just needed to populate an array with my sheet names that needed to be deleted and do Sheets(ArrayVariableName).Delete . 

However, I noticed all sheet names in array had to be present in the workbook for them to be deleted. Would there be a way to workaround that? For if the sheetnames existing in the workbook were found in the array then they can be deleted.

Comment: Are these all of the worksheets or are you deleting similar (`data`, `Sales`) worksheets for all months? Your code is additionally hiding all the remaining worksheets except "Summary". Is that a functionality that should remain in the code? Could any of the worksheets to be deleted be hidden? Be aware that at least one sheet has to be visible i.e. if `Summary` isn't found, an error will occur when hiding the last worksheet unless you have at least one visible chart in the workbook.

Comment: Hi! @VBasic2008 Yes, Summary is the only one remaining and it will always be present. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no pattern to the sheets that need to be deleted, you can just list them in a string, then split it to create an array.

Then iterate through the array items and try to delete each sheet. If you use `On Error Resume Next`, it will ignore errors encountered by each delete operation.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub Setup()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim sheetsToDelete() As String
Dim sheetName As Variant

sheetsToDelete = Split("Novemberdata,Novembersales,Decemberdata,Decembersales,Januarydata,January Sales", ",")

For Each sheetName In sheetsToDelete

    On Error Resume Next
    wb.Worksheets(sheetName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

Next sheetName


End Sub
```